# Stopping enter key to click button

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have tried many ways i dont know what i miss now

```
<input id="stopBuy" class="grn" type="button" onclick="selectGT()" value="Buy Now">
```

Issue in this when we we click once on button and if mouse is over button and then we press enter it get clicked again. so i wanted to know if there is way to stop this?

I tried putting this in whole container but does not work. I have included jQuery v1.8.3

```
<script>
$('#container').keypress(function(e) {  // even try putting #stopBuy
    if(e.which == 13) { 
        e.preventDefault();
    }
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to put your code inside DOM ready `$(document).ready(function() { });` or `$(function () { })` to make it work:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#container').keypress(function(e) {  // even try putting #stopBuy
        if(e.which == 13) { 
            e.preventDefault();
        }
   });
});
```

Comment: `var key = e.which || e.keyCode; if(key===13){`

Comment: `$(document).ready(function() { });` this worked out thanks so much. Not sure if it will work in all browser. But i will check thanks @Felix

Comment: @Allison yes. it will work in every existent browser.

Comment: this will work in all browser may be in not old version of IE @allison

Answer (score 0):

Maybe if you stop event propagation ?

```
$('#container').keypress(function(e) {  // even try putting #stopBuy
   if(e.which == 13) { 
      e.preventDefault();
      e.stopPropagation();
   }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Blur the button after it is clicked:

```
$('#stopBuy').click( function() {
    $(this).blur();
});
```